# Laravel Mail issue using nested @components with markdown

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-blade, laravel-mail

I am experiencing a problem where the code works but sometimes it fails to display the proper info in the outermost `@component`; the logo it shows is wrong, **like if it's caching the outermost layout and using it on the next    call, but with outdated info**

The issue happens while sending emails, which are run on queues.

The relevant part of the code is as follows:

1: the mail I'm trying to send (works 100% of the time)
markdown.blade.php

```
@component('mail::message')
# @lang('emails.bookingRequestReceipt', ['user' => $association->person->account->first_name, 'school' => $bookingRequest->school->name])

{!! html_entity_decode($custom_intro) ?? '' !!}

@endcomponent
```

2: the message component (works 100% of the time)

```
@component('mail::layout')

<!-- THIS IS THE RELEVANT PART -->
{{-- Header --}}
@slot('header')
@component('mail::header', ['url' => $school['url'] ?? config('app.url')])
@if(!empty($school['logo']) && !$school['logo']['default'])
<img src="{{ $school['logo']['url'] }}" class="logo" alt="{{ $school['logo']['alt'] }}" />
@elseif(empty($school))
<img src="https://[redacted]/public/img/logo.png" class="logo" alt="{{ config('app.name') }}" />
@else
{{ $school->name }}
@endif
@endcomponent
@endslot
<!-- END OF RELEVANT PART -->

{{-- Body --}}
{{ $slot }}

@endcomponent
```

3: the layout (fails)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>

<table class="wrapper" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation">
<tr>
<td align="center">
<table class="content" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation">

<!-- THIS IS THE RELEVANT PART -->
{{ $header ?? '' }}
<!-- END OF RELEVANT PART -->

<!-- Email Body -->
<tr>
<td class="body" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<table class="inner-body" align="center" width="570" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation">
<!-- Body content -->
<tr>
<td class="content-cell">
{{ Illuminate\Mail\Markdown::parse($slot) }}

</td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>

</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? The informations regarding the `$school` inside the message are always correct

Is it beacause I haven' used `php artisan make:component` to create the layout?

EDIT: removed leftover code

Answer (score 4):

I've added the mail files you provided locally to test whats causing the issues. Without knowing how and what you are returning from your Mail class (`return $this->markdown(...)` ??), I noticed a few things about the code examples:

1. About the wrong shown logo:
   You aren't passing the `$school` variable to the `message` blade, so your logo never could be shown and the `@elseif(empty($school))` will always be true.

   ```
   // message.blade.php
   @component('mail::message', ['school' => $school])
   ```
2. Your `message.blade.php` contains too many @end directives, the last two @ directives causing errors in the blade, remove these:

   ```
       ...
       {{-- Body --}}
       {{ $slot }}

   @endcomponent
   {{-- @endslot -- }} // Causes problems
   {{-- @endcomponent -- }} // Causes problems
   ```

If I fix the code snippets you provided like I explained in the steps above, everything is working fine.
Please let me know if this fix your problems.

Comment: I tried the first fix, seems reasonable. Time will tell if this was the correct solution but I have high hopes for it. The second part is some code I didn't clear properly while copying the files (otherwise nobody was gonna read everything)

Comment: Re-reading your answer (point 1): the `elseif` is actually false, it outputs some other `$school`

Answer (score 0):

In this case, if you are sure 100% that all code lines are correct. Then it would be best if you tried to **restart** the queue worker on the server.

Comment: I do this everyday but it is not this the fix :(